# Object defineProperty confuses the way I think about hoisting / sync and async js

Tags: javascript, increment, getter-setter

I thought I had a good understanding of async / sync / hoisting, when it came to how a browser loads data and presents it to the user. However this following example is throwing me for a loop, let me post the example and then explain the question:

```js
var obj = {
  counter: 0,
};

Object.defineProperty(obj, 'reset', {
  get: function() {
    return this.counter = 2;
  }
});

Object.defineProperty(obj, "increment", {
  get: function() {
    return this.counter++;
  }
});

Object.defineProperty(obj, "decrement", {
  get: function() {
    return this.counter--;
  }
});

console.log(obj.reset) //2
console.log(obj.increment + ' ' + "incremented") // "2 incremented"
console.log(obj.decrement + ' ' + "decremented") // "3 decremented"
```

I ***thought*** that the way the browser would interpret this would be to run every line of code synchronously which should produce:

```
//2
//2 incremented
//2 decremented
```

because if you where to track the changes to 'counter' all the way until the console logs are called, counter would change from 0 to 2 to 3 back down to 2.

And then I ***thought*** well wait a second; if the values being returned are not all 2 then maybe calling these console logs is an asynchronous way about getting the data which would then logically lead me to think the result should be:

```
//2
//3
//2
```

because if you where to access the 'counter' property upon the time of running the console log then logicly the counter value would change from 0 to ***2 upon (obj.reset)*** and then ***3 upon(obj.increment)*** and then ***2 again upon(obj.decrement)***

I am obviously wrong about the way im approaching how the browser interprets this and would like a clear step by step explanation of why the values being returned are:

```
//2
//2 incremented
//3 decremented
```

if at all possible, thank you.

Comment: This has nothing to do with asynchrony or hoisting, it's just how the post-increment and post-decrement operators work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to with asynchronous. `console.log` is receiving an expression and it's printing that value. `obj.increment` returns 2 because that's how [postfix `++`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Increment_()) operator works. It increments the number and returns the value before incrementing. So, it ends up being

```
console.log(2 + ' ' + "incremented")
```

`console.log()` method ends up getting the string `2 incremented`. The same logic applies to `decrement`. The expression becomes  `console.log(3 + ' ' + "decremented")`

Answer (score 1):

did you notice this ?

```js
var cpt_A = 5;
var cpt_B = 5;

function func_A(){ return cpt_A-- } 
function func_B(){ return --cpt_B } 

console.log ( func_A() )   //  return 5.
console.log ( func_B() )   //  return 4.
```

It is a basic of the programming of languages resulting from C. in the case func_A it returns the value of cpt_A, then it does the operation of decrementation. in the case func_B it does the operation of decrementation on cpt_B, then it returns the result.

Comment: Shouldn't the decrement operator be after the cpt_B like so cpt_B--? and shouldn't func_A return 4?

Comment: No, it's two differents action order. It's a classic case.